# How to get the count of first character in all the words into an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

Im new to spark and I am trying to get the count of first alphabet each word starts with.
I have the following input file.
sales file:

```
Liverpool,100,Red
Leads United,100,Blue
ManUnited,100,Red
Chelsea,300,Blue
```

I got the word count by doing the below steps.

```
val input = sc.textFile("salesfile")
val words = input.flatMap(word => word.split(",")
val wCount = words.map(words => (words,1))
val result = wCount.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

Im getting the word count by the above code.
But Im unable to write a logic to take the first alphabet of each word into an RDD. Can anyone let me know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to ignore numbers:

```
val words = input.flatMap(word => word.split(","))
// "Liverpool","100","Red","Leads United", etc. -- includes numbers

val wCount = words.filter(word => Character.isLetter(word.head)) // ignores numbers
                  .map(word => (word.head, 1)) // gets the first letter of each word
val result = wCount.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val words = input.flatMap(word => word.split(","))
//note: your words will be the Array("Liverpool","100","Red","Leads United",....) 
//idk if that's what you're looking for, but that's the example that was provided

//words(0) gets the first char from each string
val lWords = words.map(words => (words(0),1))
val result = lCount.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)

scala> result.collect().foreach(println)
(R,2)
(1,3)
(3,1)
(B,2)
(C,1)
(L,2)
(M,1)
```